# Как вставить заданное предложение после строки с номером k в текстовый файл?

Tags: c++, файлы, ввод

Задача: вставить заданное предложение после строки с номером k в текстовый файл. Если строка, в которую нужно вставить предложение уже заполнена, то сдвинуть её и вместо неё вставить данное предложение

Понятия не имею, как реализовывать вторую часть задачи. Смог сделать только для случая, если файл пустой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string str;
    int k;
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    getline (cin,str);

    cout << "Введите номер строки, после которой требуется вставить: ";
    cin >> k;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("text.txt");

    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        fout << "\n";
    }

    fout << str;
    fout.close();

    _getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, чтобы дописать к началу непустой k-той строки, тебе надо дойти до (k-1)-строки и в конце дописать "\n" + новый_текст

Comment: да всё верно, но как это реализовать?

Comment: Хм, можно открыть файл для чтения, считать в переменную строки от первой, до k-1, k-тую пропустить, но вместо нее дописать в переменную нужный текст, потом продолжить чтение до конца. После этого открыть файл для перезаписи и записать значение переменной в файл

Comment: Максимум, как я смог сделать, это считать весь файл, а потом пытался через поиск находить переносы на следующую строку... В общем у меня код не рабочий. Вашу идею я понимаю, но как её реализовать? Как считать считать данные с файла до определённой строки?

Comment: А хотя, можно через цикл for считывать данные с getline, так пойдёт?

Comment: Лучше через while (!file.eof())

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что значит эта запись?

Comment: Исполнять цикл, пока не достигнут конец файла. Ну а getline будет возвращать строку и сдвигать курсор на следующую.

Comment: Он мне пишет Erorr: индефикатор file не определён

Comment: Вместо file тебе надо подставить свою переменную, в которую открывается файл на чтение (ifstream).

Comment: Всё, разобрался, огромное спасибо! Превосходная идея!